# Admins having to reload page to see admin features (question about cookie location)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, authentication

I am creating a custom cookie and have overloaded the Iprincipal class and all that good stuff. My cookie works correctly and I am able to retrieve the roles of the users successfully, but the admins have to reload the default page after just logging in to see the admin only button. Once they visit a new page on my site and return to the default page, the button is there.

I read somewhere that the cookie is created last and has something to do with a response to the HTTP. TBH, I am new to this stuff and don't understand exactly how that works, but I see how it effects my program.

I am currently creating and planting my cookie in the page load of my default page. Should I be doing it somewhere else, perhaps in the log-in page? I tried that, but the same issue still exists. Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help and I would be more than happy to clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try setting the cookie and redirecting.  this is somewhat standard practice during login.  the redirect will cause a fresh page load during which your cookie will be sent to the server.

Comment: Ok, that is something that I was thinking about. I know this is a trivial question, but what would be the best way to do that without creating a redirect loop?

Thanks for the answer, I appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I figured out a way to do it. I just checked to see if the user, who was already logged in, was in the general user role, which all users are, and if not I reloaded the page. This way I only reload the page if the cookie has not taken effect and will not create a redirect loop.

Thanks again for the solution. I will accept it as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

When I started ASP.NET, I often ran into a similar issue.  The problem was that I didn't bind the data properly AFTER the button click occurred:

Bad Code:

```
void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    _adminControls.Visibile = IsAdmin();
}

void Login_Clicked(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    DoLogin();
}
```

The way to fix it is:

```
void Page_Load(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    // Move binding code, etc to a BindData function and only call it if !IsPostBack
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}

void BindData()
{
    _adminControls.Visibile = IsAdmin();
}

void Login_Clicked(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    DoLogin();
    BindData(); // Call BindData function after login
}
```

This may not be what you are seeing, but the symptoms are similar.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that up. I see what you are saying and will keep this issue in mind while wrapping up my program. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are set and read by the server on a subsequent HTTP response.

You can try embedding an iframe or something else that sends it in the same page.

This is what I did, for example:
1. I had the page user lands on directly. Cookies are set. But for this page, the server can't read the cookies as it needs a reload.

2. I can force a http reload with a different random character as a GET parameter but this is ugly (as the reloaded page with the GET parameter will get indexed, and create un-necessary complications)
3. On the landing page, I want to already display stuff depending on the cookie set or not (or show alternate content if there's no cookie)

```
//in the head tags:
 $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#my_div").load("/MYajax/footer_links.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
                            if(statusTxt == "success")
                              console.log("my_div loaded successfully!");
                            if(statusTxt == "error")
                              console.log ("my_div Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                          });
 });
```

And then somewhere within the page:

```
<div id="my_div"></mydiv>
```

and in /path/myfile.html do whatever you would like to do with cookies present or not present

Basically with jquery load, there is a new http request sent to /path/myfile.html and cookies are read, if any.