# Set cookie in a funtion, then check on page reload and do something

Tags: jquery, cookies, reload

I would like to set a value for a cookie at the end of a function and on page reload, check for the existence of that code. Something like:

```
function onObjectDrag() {
// save code
$.cookie("saved", 1);
location.reload();
}
```

Then when the page is refreshed, check if that cookie exists and if so, do something then delete the cookie. If not, don't do anything.

Comment: you're saving the cookie. now in the document.ready event just read the cookie value and "do something" and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call `onObjectDrag()` without any condition or after you set the cookie to zero or else you will end up with a recursion.

```
function onObjectDrag() {
    setCookie('saved', 1, 100);
    location.reload();
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var x = getCookie('saved');
    if (x == 1) {
        //do something
        setCookie('saved', 0, 100);
    }
});

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly @hoschnok. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just embed another http request in the same page and avoid stuff like reloading...

Reloading may cause you headaches with bookmarked pages, indexed pages on search engines, people directly linking to the reloaded page, etc.

See [Admins having to reload page to see admin features (question about cookie location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345644/admins-having-to-reload-page-to-see-admin-features-question-about-cookie-locati/57314485#57314485) if it helps you