# Send a fetch when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use a TimeTracker on my website. It is like a simple timer. So when i start the timer and stop it the time which has passed is written to the database.
But when the user reload the page the timer is reset. But I want that the time is stored in the database by a pagerelaod.
For my Project I use React and Typescript.
My question is, how i could recognize when the page is relaod and befor I want to store the time into the database. Is it possible?

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711705/7518261

Answer (score 2):

`componentWillUnmount` will not work because it won't get called when the user refreshes or leave your page.

Using the [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) + `fetch` seems tempting but won't work either due to the asynchronous nature of `fetch`.

However, [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) was made specifically for the use of sending HTTP requests on page unload!

Another caveat, but you won't be able to use it with `onbeforeunload`, you'll have to use it with page visibility instead. It's a long story, in short it only works on dekstop but not on mobile. Here's [an article that deep dives on this issue](https://www.igvita.com/2015/11/20/dont-lose-user-and-app-state-use-page-visibility/)

All in all your code should look like:

```js
window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
    navigator.sendBeacon(
      'url/of/your/database',
      JSON.stringify({ your: 'payload' }),
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: This won't work if the browser (or device) crashes.

Comment: I mean, there's no way to make things work on case of device crash except from sending data to the database at every update that happens on the front-end...

Comment: This is the right answer. Since the question specifically asks about page reload, note that the request for the new page probably will hit your web server _before_ the request where you save your payload. That means you won't be able to read that write (since it hasn't happened yet), and the refreshed page will potentially still display stale data. However, it has been saved, so you need to reload one more time.

Answer (score -1):

Try: `window.onbeforeunload`, but not `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not the answer you want but there is no good way to confirm that a function will run before a page is unmounted (for example what if the users' browser crashes), so the ideal way would be to store the timer start time in the database and the return the record id to the front end and put somewhere that is persisted (like in the URL path) so the user can refer back to it at a later time, then you can run the timer based on the start time of the record, then if the user reloads the page you first fetch the record from the database and start the timer based on the start time again.

This is a more complicated way of doing it but in my opinion the only safe way to do it.